# Address of reference variable in c++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I have the following c++ code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 int a=100;
 int  &b = a;

int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{

    cout << " a  "<<a<<"  b"<<b<<endl;
    b = 200;
    cout <<"a "<<a<<endl;
}
```

I would like to see the address of both a, and b in symbol table of the object file?

```
#gcc -g -o ref ref.cpp -lstdc++
```

There are tools like objdump, readelf. but i am not familiar with these tools. Kindly proivde the suggession way to find address of a, and b in object file [ ie: In symbol table ]

NOTE: I have edited to move variables from local to global.

Comment: What do you mean by their address in the object file? Those are stack (automatic) variables. They shouldn't appear anywhere in a symbol table. (Only in debugging information.)

Comment: @Mat, my mistake. I made both variables are global now.

Answer (score 4):

Address of Reference variable is same as the address of the object it refers to.
i.e:

```
&b == &a
```

And this is well defined by the standard and will always be true.
What are trying to achieve?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes I know it doesn't answer the Q directly, but there is no real need of the Q, this is well defined and will always be true.I get the feeling that OP is trying to prove to himself a fact that is already well known.Anyhow, on second thoughts, I will delete this answer if OP is aware of this fact and says so.

Comment: I would like to see how the references are made in assembly code.

Comment: From what I understood, Whoami is asking in terms of how the things are internally implemented, not language semantics. Internally, a reference is in fact a pointer. The semantics imply auto-dereferencing of such pointer, but that doesn't mean it is not required to be stored somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
  cout << " &a  " << &a <<"  &b "<< &b <<endl;
```

This will show the address of both, and confirm that they are at the same address.

Answer (score 0):

These are local variables that get allocated on the stack. Memory and hence an address is obtained when the program is run.

You will not get an address from an object file.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to see the address is really with tools like objdump, but you'll never see the address of local variables. They don't exist at compile time, are allocated in the stack at runtime. The only thing you'll see in the exe is the asm/machine code that does the push or sub sp, which is the allocation.

If you change your program to:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char ** argv)
{
    static int a=100;
    static int  &b = a;
    cout << " a  "<<a<<"  b"<<b<<endl;
    b = 200;
    cout <<"a "<<a<<endl;
}
```

then after compiling do:

objdump -t ref | grep data

and you'll see:

```
080488a8 l    d  .rodata        00000000              .rodata
08049a94 l    d  .data          00000000              .data
080488bc l     O .rodata        00000004              _ZZ4mainE6b
08049a9c l     O .data          00000004              _ZZ4mainE6a
08049a94  w      .data          00000000              data_start
080488a8 g     O .rodata        00000004              _fp_hw
080488ac g     O .rodata        00000004              _IO_stdin_used
08049a94 g       .data          00000000              __data_start
08049a98 g     O .data          00000000              .hidden __dso_handle
08049aa0 g       *ABS*          00000000              _edata
```

The variables you're looking for are _ZZ4mainE6a _ZZ4mainE6b (these are their mangled names).

EDIT: for the current version of your sample code, with a & b as globals, a will be .text and b .rodata, so now you'd have to use "text" in the grep filter to see a.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, from such output can we make out if both variables points to same address?.

Comment: No, because the address of a is the address of its int value, and the address of b is the address of an address (that in runtime will contain the address of a). But you'll see that the value of b is the address of a if you look at the offset of b in the .rodata section dumped by objdump -D (notice that the byte ordering will be inverted, since you're in a little-endian machine)

Comment: Also notice that all the addresses contained in the executable file are in fact offsets, not actual addresses. When running the program they'll be added to the process base address to produce the effective addresses.

Comment: 1) Address of  'a' is the address of int value. Understood. 2) Value of 'b' is the address of 'a' -> In this case b should print the address of 'a' rather than value right ?. c) offset value of b shows "00000004", how can i map this to address of 'a'. Kindly help :).

Comment: The offset is the first column (08049a9c); 00000004 is the size. That b doesn't print the address of a is due to C++ semantics: to the programmer, a reference doesn't exist by itself, it's simply like an alias for the referenced variable. It's important to differentiate the behavior of the language to how such behavior is internally implemented. If you want to have access to b as a separated entity, you should make it be a pointer (or a const pointer, if you will), not a reference. This is what Als is talking about in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "nm" tool on the final executable file.
Like this:

$ nm -C hello
080490ba A __bss_start
080490ba A _edata
080490bc A _end
08048083 T _start
08048080 t access.the.bsd.kernel
080490ac d hbytes
080490ac d hello
$

The first column of the output is an address of a symbol, after that goes its type and after that its name.